# Is it possible to compile and run java without using any shell?

Tags: java, bash, shell

This question just popped to my mind.
To compile java, we need to use the $JAVA_HOME/bin/javac file and pass to it the java files that needs to be compiled.
I was wondering if it is possible to execute javac file without using the bash/shell.
Or use any other programming languages to execute the javac file directly?

Comment: Any method of executing a program will do.  All the shell does is fork a process and run `javac` in the new process.  There's nothing stopping you from writing a, say, C program, to do the same thing.

Comment: you must compile your sources. what are you trying to do?

Comment: How do you think a shell executes `javac`? Unlike [turtles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down), it's not shells all the way down.

Comment: If I create a new process, how can i run javac in that process?
can you give me an example in c/java ?

Comment: I am trying to bridge php/node with java.
To do this, i have to compile the java with the shell command run via a child process, and i was thinking if i can ski that shell execution completely @JossefHarush

Comment: @FFgTYnh you can also execute a `jar` file

Comment: Can you elaborate what practical problem you are trying to solve?  Or is it just a theoretical musing which lead to this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void)
{
  execl( "/path/javac","javac", "/path/to/program.java", NULL );
  return 0;
}
```

That C program will execute the compiler and compile program.java without using a shell. Just run it also without using a shell and you have run the compiler without a shell.
It is not a very useful program, it always compiles the same single file. But it is possible to modify it to read a file with a list of files to compile. Which is actually what IDEs do. And that is another way of running javac without a shell.

As for running the compiled java program the same principle applies. Create a program which runs the java interpreter.

Comment: Ha ha!  Now you can write a C program to start your C program in order to avoid the shell completely ;-)

Comment: He he! But such a thing has already been done. KDE, Gnome, Windows' explorer, etc...

Comment: ...and what do you think the shell is?  A C program!

Comment: The point is, you offer a wrapper which still needs to be called.  Whoever can call that wrapper, probably also can call the `javac` directly.  So what's the point of the wrapper C program?

Comment: @cdarke. Yes. Or  an ADA program or any other language. If your point is that any program that lauches another program is considered a shell then, yes it is impossible to compile and run Java without using a shell

Comment: i executed execl( "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javac", "-d","~/workstation/checkme/build/classes/","~/workstation/checkme/src/*.java" );
but I am not receiving any compiled file to the mentioned folder. @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos

Comment: @FFgTYnh, do not use the `~` or the `*` in your command.  The shell (which you are not using) would expand this before calling the program.  You can type in a shell sth like `echo /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javac -d ~/workstation/checkme/build/classes/ ~/workstation/checkme/src/*.java` to see what the shell expands this to.

Comment: @FFgTYnh as Alfe said use full paths. Also my parameters to execl were not correct. I have updated my answer. 1st parameter is full path to executable. 2nd is executable name. Then all the parameters to javac and finish with NULL. If you want to compile all java files then you will have to type each of them separated. Y just tested it and it works.

Comment: I was not passing the spaces as param, ex: execl( "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javac"," ","-version", NULL);
thanks for the help

Comment: You don't need to and should not pass spaces as parameters. Your example works because javac does not care if you call it " ". But that would confuse anyone reading the code. Just do your example as : execl( "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javac","javac","-version", NULL);

Comment: why are you using the "javac" as the 2nd parameter? the "path/to/javac" is itself an eecutable file and will act for the javac command @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos

Comment: check http://linux.die.net/man/3/execl  . "The const char *arg and subsequent ellipses in the execl(), execlp(), and execle() functions can be thought of as arg0, arg1, ..., argn. Together they describe a list of one or more pointers to null-terminated strings that represent the argument list available to the executed program. The first argument, by convention, should point to the filename associated with the file being executed. ". In other words : 2nd arg of execl is what the program will receive as argv[0], 3rd as argv[1] and so on.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos: is was more a comment for the OP rather than your good self.  The definition of a shell is subjective, but what most people (including the OP) mean involves a CLI.  They forget that shells like bash or ksh are just ordinary C programs.  Microsoft define Windows Explorer as a shell, which is semantically correct but many UNIX people would not recognise is as being a shell because it doesn't have a command-line.  So really the question should have defined what the OP meant as "shell", but I think we can guess.

Answer (score -2):

It is not possible to use javac without, on some level, executing it as a shell command, because by its nature it is a command line program. This means that it can be executed from any programming language that can execute native shell commands.

What most people do after learning how javac works by executing it manually from a shell is configure their IDE to execute javac with the correct arguments when developing, and configure a build technology such as maven or ant to execute javac to produce their deployable application package.

Comment: A shell is just one (very common) way to execute other programs.  You can of course avoid it completely, e. g. by setting a different program as login shell for your user in `/etc/passwd`.  This is so unusual you will run into lots of problems, but it can be done.

Comment: interesting - I consider myself schooled!